# Concurrency and multiple user access

Tags: c#, winforms, concurrency

First of all I would explain the situation.
I have a GUI which is stored on a server and should gain multiple user access. Users are working on different tabs (kind of separated workspaces). 
Now when a user enters a tab it should be locked for other users  (disabled).Other users should see if a tab is currently locked.
So my ideas on this are:

1. Create a textfile which lists the tabs and their current status  (locked-unlocked).
2. A thread checks every few seconds if that file was modified. If yes then read it and disable or enable the corresponding tabs in the GUI.
   3.When a user wants to enter a tab, check the file if the tab is unlocked (maybe a user was faster than the thread) and set it to locked.

When a user leaves a tab then set it to unlocked.

Now my questions are:

Is there a better or more efficient way to handle this situation?

And how to avoid the case that two users want to switch to the same tab at the same time, read that the tab is unlocked and write at the same time into the file?

Are there even more error cases?

Comment: Maybe this is a question for [Programmers SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: Up to my knowledge it is not possible to store a winforms app on server and access it by multiple users and you must install your app on every user's system separately. How you are storing a winforms app on server and allowing multiple users to access it?

Comment: @RameshBabu. The server simply exposes a share to all users and the app resides on that share. There's no trickery involved.

Comment: Exactly. This should work.

Comment: @David Amo Thank you for clarifying my doubt.

Comment: @UweKeim when referring other sites, it is often helpful to point that [cross-posting is frowned upon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/cross-posting/info)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understand from your question that you need to synchronize the applications running on different computers. You want to do it through a file located on a network drive, that is accessed from all of these computers, right?

Except shared file you can use IP/Ethernet broadcasting, or simple synchronizing server.

Among all these solutions the shared file is most simple, but no so effective.

Instead of it you can use similar technique with `System.IO.FileSystemWatcher`. In case of file watcher you'll create single file for each tab while it's locking; and delete it while tab is releasing.

File watcher frees you from having to re-read the content of the file, it raises an event instead when the file is changed.

This method would work with no so high load. If you're planning >50 users I think it's better to develop special server to synchronize users.

Short instructions:

1. Place `FileSystemWatcher` control on a form.
2. Setup property `Path` to desired network path (it's better to use new empty directory).
3. Create handlers for event `Create` and `Delete`:

   ```
   void fileSystemWatcher1_Created(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
   {
       var tabName = Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath);
       var tab = tabControl1.TabPages[tabName];

       // Do not disable selected tab cause you're working with the tab
       // and you're locking it
       if (tab != tabControl1.SelectedTab)
           tab.Enabled = false;
   }

   void fileSystemWatcher1_Deleted(object sender, FileSystemEventArgs e)
   {
       var tabName = Path.GetFileName(e.FullPath);
       var tab = tabControl1.TabPages[tabName];
       tab.Enabled = true;
   }
   ```

When a tab gets focus, you should create empty file with the tab name in the network directory:

```
. . .
var path = fileSystemWatcher1.Path;
var filename = Path.Combine(path, tabControl1.SelectedTag.Name);
using (File.Create(filename));
```

When a tab losts focus: you should delete file:

```
var path = fileSystemWatcher1.Path;
var filename = Path.Combine(path, tabControl1.SelectedTag.Name);
File.Delete(filename);
```

Comment: No there are just about 5-10 users. That sounds very good. Do you have an example somewhere? That would be great.

Comment: @Jackson30 I added examples in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much for this solution!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of a text file, you could use a proper SQL DBMS and transactions to keep the checking and updating atomic. It will cover all edge cases if you write your queries properly.

Something like:

```
begin tran
if not exists(select top 1 1 from tabs where id=@id and active=1)
begin
    update tabs set active=1 where id=@id
    select 1 --result
end
else
begin
    select 0 --result
end
commit tran
```

Or even better, instead of just storing true/false to mean that the tab is in use, store a user identifier to know who's using it. That way if your application crashes/ends before releasing it, you can manually release it next time the same user logs in. You can also throw in an expiration date for the same purpose, and keep pushing it back while the application is online.

Comment: That with the user id is a good idea. I would rather not use an external software like DBMS. Only if there would be no other way to realize this.

Answer (score -1):

I feel xml file will be better than text file for this. As specified in the question you need to maintain status of each tab in the xml file indicating whether it is locked. you can handle `selecting` event of the tab control in which the type parameter `e` is `TabControlCancelEventArgs` and has the property `Cancel` by setting which to true will cancel selecting that tab. within this event you can check the xml file to verify that the tab is locked or unlocked and if locked, you can set `e.Cancel=true` and give a message to the user that this tab is locked.

you can use `deselecting` event of the tab control to know when a user moves out of that tab and update the status of that tab in xml file to unlocked.